# masonry images coming out oddly.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, jquery-masonry

This is not the issue regarding images coming out overlapping, but rather coming out of order.

I've got an application that when you search a given game, returns a list of games similar.  The issue, is that when you search a game that hasn't be chached, it spits them out in weird order, if you do the search again immediately after, it spits them out in the right order.

I have this bit of code (Which should be relevant):

```
$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
        $container.animate({ opacity:1});
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.box',
            columnWidth: 1,
            isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions
        });
    });

for ( var i=0; i < len; i++ ) {
                    item = balls();
                    items.push( item ); 
                }
                var $items = $( items.join('') );
                //Load up the initial boxes. 
                $items.imagesLoaded(function(){
                  $container
                    .append( $items ).masonry( 'appended', $items, true );
                });

function balls(){
    $iterator -= 1;
    if($iterator < 0){
        var $boxes = $( '<div class="box">No more games!</div>' );
        $container.append( $boxes ).masonry( 'appended', $boxes, false );   
        return; 
    }
    return (
        '<div class="box" style="width:18%">'
        +'<p>'+$test[$iterator][1][2]['name']+'</p>'
        +'<img src="scripts/php/timthumb.php?src='+$test[$iterator][2]+'&q=100&w=300"/>' //Replace this with the one below when timthumb is whitelisted
        +'<div id=boxBottom>'+Math.floor($test[$iterator][0]*100)+'%</div>'
        +'</div>'
    );
}
```

If you do a console.log() on `items`, then you see they are in order, but again, they come out wrong.

The website is here: http://newgameplus.nikuai.net/

You can see what its doing.  Sorry I didn't make a jsfiddle, it's pulling games from a database.

If there's anything unclear, I'll do my best to make it so.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to add a masonry("reload") function to the  jquery append function. I think it doesn't hurt but I'm wonder why your columnWidth is 1? If I remember it should be a multiple of the surrounding container but not 1?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply,I tried that, and it causes the boxes to appear much frather down the rather than up near the top.  Unsure of why.  My biggest question I think is am I useing the imagesLoaded function correctly?  Because though it is adjusting the boxes right for teh size, the caching issue would indicate that perhaps it's not loading properly.

Comment: Adola: It looks right I use it also like this. See my homepage: http://www.chihoang.de. Maybe your columnWidth is too small? My columnWidth is the same of a picture. Another problem is what cache do you mean?

Comment: Well, it's what I suspect.  See, when you FIRST search a game, it'll spit out bad results, but then say you reload the page, and do it again, it works perfectly fine.  And the column width, if it's not set to 1, it makes the boxes space out HUGE.

Comment: Adola: well I suspect not the cache it's working on my site? Have you tried prepend instead? If you add the correct columnwidth and you have huge gaps something is wrong. maybe update jquery and masonry? Also do you need modernizer?

Comment: Prepend might not be what I want, then the data wouldn't get put in the right order.  And the columnwidth is to make sure its tight together, if I set it to say 10, then there's 10 pixels inbetween each box, and that doesnt' look good.  Jquery is updated, and to my understanding, modernizer makes the fluid animations.  Which i want.

Comment: You can make a jsfiddle with some empty boxes? Other thing I would try is to add widht and height to the images. I assume the images doesn't have width and height attributes?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is too much to ask, but, I think I'm probably doing it wrong.  Is there anyway you can do a jsfiddle with empty boxes?  Something that mimics the behviour that Im' trying to do on the site. 

I ask becuase if I can see your example, then I can find out why mine is wrong.

Comment: Modernizer is just a css selector masonry does all the calculation. When you look at my page you can see that prepend or append doesn't change the result of masonry. Masonry has a serious background in bin-packing problem and operation research. I also like it because it looks good but it's simple to achieve with jquery animate function.

Comment: I certainly wasn't asking you to do my code for me, just an example.  That's fine I'll figure it out on my own.

Comment: Here is jsfiddle from another user: http://jsfiddle.net/ArgyleGost/VBacg/29/. But you should look into masonry documentation and bin-packing to fully understand. I hope it helps!